# Docker/Kubernetes with on premise servers

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, kubernetes, continuous-deployment

I have a *.NET core web API* and *Angular 7* app that I need to deploy to multiple client servers, potentially running a plethora of different OS setups.

Dockerising the whole app seems like the best way to handle this, so I can ensure that it all works wherever it goes.

My question is on my understanding of Kubernetes and the distribution of the application. We use Azure Dev Ops for build pipelines, so if I'm correct would it work as follows:

1) Azure Dev Ops builds and deploys the image as a Docker container.
2) Kubernetes could realise there is a new version of the docker image and push this around all of the different client servers? 
3) Client specific app settings could be handled by Kubernetes secrets.

Is that a reasonable setup? Have I missed anything? And are there any recommendations on setup/guides I can follow to get started.

Thanks in advance, James

Comment: Azure DevOps builds the project and pushes a docker image to an azure container registry and then kubernetes builds pods with containers based on image from this registry.

Comment: It's a reasonable setup. Maybe you should consider [keel](https://keel.sh/) as a tool which will trigger k8s when there is a new docker image released.

Comment: Kubernetes is fairly simple in its functionality actually. It just looks at your helm charts and makes your cluster conform to that. If you specified 3 instances and there's only 2, it will spin up another. If the helm chart says it should be using myimage:v2 but it has myimage:v1 nodes, then it spins up myimage:v2 nodes and spins down the myimage:v1 nodes. The trick is largely in tagging your images and then updating the tags in the helm chart.

Comment: @IvanAracki thanks Ivan, I'll take a look at Keel

Comment: @Dimitar thanks for the suggestion, so would I have Kubernetes installed on my clients servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure DevOps will perform the CI part of your pipeline. Once it is completed, Azure DevOps will push images to ACR. CD part should be done either directly from Azure DevOps (You may have to install a private agent on your on-prem servers & configure firewall etc) or Kubernetes native CD tools such as [Spinnaker](https://www.spinnaker.io/) or [Jenkins-X](https://jenkins-x.io/). Secrets should be kept in Kubernetes secrets.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this might be a stupid question so apologies if so. But how would I run a Kubernetes cluster on a windows server?

Comment: You can use Docker for Windows and enable Kubernetes. This is helpful for Dev\Testing. For full fledged production ready Kubernetes Windows cluster, [Intro to Windows support in Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/windows/) might be a good starting point.